# Django and kwargs why do I get this?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a dict doing the following

```
data = {
    'date': kwargs['this_number'],
    'Number': kwargs['number'],
}
```

However, when I print data out i.e.

```
print(data)
```

I get the following results:

```
{
    'date': datetime.date(2018, 9, 30),
    'Number': u'4929000000006'
}
```

My question is, why is Django added `datetime.date(` and `u` etc, how do I get rid of them? I need the raw data for a POST

Comment: You have not provided enough info here. What arguments are being passed to the function? What code is calling the function? Why don't you want a `datetime` object? What were you expecting? What are you doing with the `data` once you have it? Why don't you expect the string to be Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a dictionary its items aren't `str`-ified but `repr`-ified. This is for good reason; if it were `str`-ified then `{"foo", "22"}` would print as `{foo: 22}`!

You can get around this by manually printing your dictionary:

```
import datetime

my_dict = {'date': datetime.date(2018, 9, 30),'Number': u'4929000000006'}

def substring(item):
    if isinstance(item, unicode):
        return repr(item)[1:]

    if isinstance(item, datetime.date):
        return repr(str(item))

    return repr(item)

def dict_substrings(dict):
    yield u"{"

    if my_dict:
        nameitems = my_dict.iteritems()
        name, item = next(nameitems)

        yield substring(name)
        yield u": "
        yield substring(item)

        for name, item in nameitems:
            yield u", "

            yield substring(name)
            yield u": "
            yield substring(item)

    yield u"}"

def dict_representation(dict):
    return "".join(dict_substrings(dict))

print(dict_representation(my_dict))
```

The key function is `substring` which you should modify manually to output stuff the way you want it to. It's a bit long-winded for efficiency, in order to keep it `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x a `u` means its a unicode object but its very similar to a string object, To convert it into raw data just use either `str()` method or `int()` method

```
>>> type(u'K-DawG')
<type 'unicode'>

>>> type('K-DawG')
<type 'str'>

>>> type(str(u'K-DawG'))
<type 'str'>
```

**But in python 3.x**, a unicode object is regarded as a *string*, so in your case a `int()` method is all that's needed to convert that numeral which is considered a *string*

```
>>> type(u'K-DawG')
<class 'str'>

>>> type(int(u'12'))
<class 'int'>
```

To get the date as a string and as not as a `datetime.date` object use the `.isoformat()` method:

```
data = {
    'date': datetime.date(2018, 9, 30).isoformat(),
    'Number': int(u'4929000000006'),
}
print(data)
```

This would print : `{'Number': 4929000000006, 'date': '2018-09-30'}`

*Note: I directly used `datetime.date(2018, 9, 30)` instead of `kwargs['this_number']` is because, you haven't stated more information or haven't exposed more needed code anyway what I've stated must be enough*